# Convert a string into an R vector expression

Tags: haskell, regex

Problem: Given a arbitrary string, split by a given regex and format into an R vector expression. E.g. Convert "a..,b..,c,d" into 'c("a","b","c","d")', when the given regex is "[.,]+".

Solution in haskell:

```
module Lib
    ( toRVec
    ) where


import           Data.List  (intersperse)
import           Data.Maybe (fromMaybe)
import           Data.Text  ()
import           Data.Text  (pack, strip, unpack)
import           Text.Regex (mkRegex, splitRegex)


(//) :: Maybe a -> a -> a
(//) = flip fromMaybe

stripString = (unpack . strip . pack)

toRVec :: String -> Maybe String -> Maybe Bool ->  String
toRVec orig delim' toStrip' =
  let
      delim = delim' // "[ \n]+"
      toStrip = toStrip' // True
      ws = splitRegex (mkRegex delim) $ stripString orig
      ws1 = map (\w -> "\"" ++ w ++ "\"") $ if toStrip then
                                                      map stripString ws
                                                    else
                                                      ws
      ws2 = intersperse "," ws1
      res = foldl (++) "" ws2
   in "c(" ++ res ++ ")"
```

Any suggestion for improvements are welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How I would do it:

```
import Data.List.Split
import Data.List
foo delim s = "c(\"" ++ intercalate "\",\"" (wordsBy (`elem` delim) s) ++ "\")"
```

*reads yours*

No brackets needed around `unpack . strip . pack`.

I would replace `if toStrip then map stripString ws else ws` with `(if toStrip then map stripString else id) ws`.

Some of your names are unneeded; I would inline ws, ws1 and ws2 into where they are used (once ws is only used once), perhaps even res.

Instead of `foldl (++)`, use `concat`.

Comment: Moreover: delim and tostrip are options, orig is what is transformed; thus orig should be the last argument. Think `Maybe String -> Maybe String -> (String -> String)`.

People usually don't provide default options as Maybe arguments, at least I don't see it. Consider dropping the lines with // and let the user plug in the default options if they want, seeing as providing default options isn't even part of the task.

Comment: If you use Gurkenglas's suggestion about `orig` being last, you could even provide a default like this:

`toRVecDefault = toRVec "[ \n]+" True`